# Heat Map using Count Field in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I'm currently trying to plot a heat map of a large data set, where each position element has an additional attribute that corresponds to a count of occurrences (let's call it n<sub>i</sub>).

I want these counts to be taken into account in the density estimate. I guess an easy approach would be to duplicate each of the elements n<sub>i</sub> times. However, as the data set is pretty large already, I would like to avoid duplication.

Is that possible in QGIS without much data pre-processing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_heatmap.html), there is a *Use weight from field* option that you can specify your occurence field. Quoting the documentation:

> This can be used to increase the influence certain features have on
>   the resultant heatmap.

Comment: @twiechert You're welcome! Please mark this answer as accepted if it solves your issue. Thanks!